# Why do I get array of features after click on one feature in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, features

There is a geojson:

```
{
  "features": [
    {
      "id": "f6105acf-065e-499b-b23d-85298dd84108",
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          55.094384525,
          51.810150862,
          106.179835026
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "properties": {
        "createDate": "2022-11-05T18:42:40.83",
        "createUser": "sight1",
        "extendedData": "{\"fields\": {\"type\": 1}}",
        "inventoryObjectType": 63,
        "panoId": 17927769,
        "status": 1,
        "taskId": "18f596db-912a-4c1f-b343-9d1e920579d0",
        "trackid": 9727
      },
      "type": "Feature"
    }
  ],
  "type": "FeatureCollection"
}
```

I catch the map click when user clicks over feature:

```
   const feature = this.mapRef.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
      evt.pixel,
      function (feature) {
        return feature;
      }
    );

    if (feature) {
      debugger;
      return;
    }
```

Why do I get features array inctead one feature (screen 1):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not complete. From `.forEachFeatureAtPixel` function result it's obvious that you vector layer source is cluster, so upon click you get cluster feature, where features that comprise the cluster are available through `.get('features')` method. That's what you see under `values_.features` property.

So to display those features in the console code could look like:

```
const feature = this.mapRef.forEachFeatureAtPixel(
  evt.pixel,
  function (feature) {
    return feature;
  }
);

if (feature) {
  console.log(feature.get('features'));
}
```

Comment: When I zoom in I get one element of cluster - feature. Alwasys I got features as array because as you meantored it is cluster. Okay. Then I need to open cluster, zoom and always to get the first element of array, right?

Comment: I have tried this: `const clusterFeatures = feature.get('features');
      if (clusterFeatures.length > 1) {
        clusterFeatures.forEach((feature) => {
          extend(extent, feature.getGeometry().getExtent());
        });

        this.mapRef
          .getView()
          .fit(extent, { duration: 1000, padding: [50, 50, 50, 50] });`

Comment: The above is answer to your question. It's customary on GIS SE site to mark it as accepted, to let others with similar questions/problems that question was answered. If you have new/additional question, please post it as a separate question.